# Conformal mapping question: Joing two rays using the transformation $f(z) = \frac{z-b}{z-a}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am currently trying to solve some problems in order to refresh my knowledge on linear fractional transformations. I am trying to conformally map the complex plain with cuts along the rays $(-\infty,a]$ and $[b,\infty)$, $a<b$, to the upper complex plain.

Well, I figured out that if I would use

$$f(z)=\frac{z-b}{z-a}$$

and take the square root $\sqrt{f(z)}$, that will do the job. This type of transformation is referred to as 'joining two rays', hence the title of my question. My logic is motivated by

$$lim_{z \to a}f(z) = \infty$$
$$lim_{z \to \infty}f(z) = 1$$
$$f(b) = 0$$

The point is, whether this is enough to prove that I will map the initial problem to the complex plane with a cut along the positive real axis, when using $f(z)$? Or more precisely, how can I prove that the new problem has a  cut that starts precisely at the origin.

In general, could you recommend a textbook where solved examples of such problems are given. Our tutor sets high priority on finding conformal maps with certain properties and I would like to teach myself how to solve them.

UPDATE:

Since I didn't attract much attention, I decided to give the problem a deeper thought. Here is what I came up with:

Well, I think that we have to check what the boundaries are mapped to. We know that: $f(b) = 0$, $f(+\infty) = 1$. Therefore, $[b,+ \infty) \to [0,1]$. (I am not sure if this should be $[0,1]$ or $[0,1)$)

The second part is a bit more confusing. $f(-\infty) = 1$ but what is $f(a)$, is it $-\infty$ or $+\infty$. This is where I start getting confused. I think that $f(a) = +\infty$. Otherwise the intervals will overlap, and we shall get multiple values for the function.

Does this make sense?

Thanks